# How to set and use connection string in C# entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

My problem is the following: I want to connect to a SQL Server Express instance on a local network with my C# application; the IP is 192.168.1.147 and the SQL Server port is 1433.

I have a code-first database running smoothly, I can connect from the PC that is hosting the service but not from another computer.

How can I set my connection string, or where should I do it? What would be the correct format? And how should I use it in my application?

I tried the following:

```
192.168.1.147\SQLEXPRESS,1433 
192.168.1.147:1433\SQLEXPRESS 
192.168.1.147,1433
```

EDIT: the connection looks like this in my `app.config`:

```
<connectionStrings> 
   <add name="Amnesia.Client.Properties.Settings.AMNContext" 
        connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.147\SQLEXPRESS,1477;Initial Catalog=Amnesia.Server.Repository.AmnesiaContext;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=whatever;Password=whatever"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Where did you try setting that string? What error or exception did you get?

Comment: Your issue is just as likely to be firewall-related, or SQL disallowing remote connections.

Comment: EF normally drops a connection string in your app.config - have you checked there?

Comment: Try `192.168.1.147:1433\SQLEXPRESS` or just simlpy `192.168.1.147\SQLEXPRESS` , 1433 is the default port for Sql server.

Comment: 192.168.1.147,1433 no instance name

Comment: Please do not paste code or question updates in comments.  Edit your question with all the relevant information, because you will more likely have a successful answer if someone doesn't have to wade through comments to see code or the real question.

Comment: Your question says you're using port 1433 but your connection string says you're using port 1477. Mistype?

Comment: also have you open up the firewall from the DB server, so other computer can connect.